# How do I remove carriage returns from text file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, replace, find

I'm outputting the contents of a directory to a txt file using the following command:

```
$SearchPath="c:\searchpath"
$Outpath="c:\outpath"

Get-ChildItem "$SearchPath" -Recurse | where {!$_.psiscontainer} | Format-Wide -Column 1'
| Out-File "$OutPath\Contents.txt" -Encoding ASCII -Width 200
```

What I end up with when I do this is a txt file with the information I need, but it adds numerous carriage returns I don't need, making the output harder to read.

This is what it looks like:

```
    c:\searchpath\directory

name of file.txt

name of another file.txt


    c:\searchpath\another directory

name of some file.txt
```

That makes a txt file that requires a lot of scrolling, but the actual information isn't that much, usually a lot less than a hundred lines.

I would like for it to look like:

```
  c:\searchpath\directory
nameoffile.txt
  c:\searchpath\another directory
another file.txt
```

This is what I've tried so far, not working

```
$configFiles=get-childitem "c:\outpath\*.txt" -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "'n", ""} | 
Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

I've also tried 'r but both options leave the file unchanged.

Another attempt:

```
Select-String -Pattern "\w" -Path 'c:\outpath\contents.txt' | foreach {$_.line}'
| Set-Content -Path c:\outpath\contents2.txt
```

When I run that string without the Set-content at the end, it appears exactly as I need it in the ISE, but as soon as I add the Set-Content at the end, it once agains carriage returns where I don't need them.

Here's something interesting, if I create a text file with a few carriage returns and a few tabs, then if I use the same -replace script I've been using, but use`t to replace the tabs, it works perfect. But`r and `n do not work. It's almost as though it doesn't recognize them as escape characters. But if I add`r and `n in the txt file then run the script, it still doesn't replace anything. Doesn't seem to know what to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set-Content` adds newlines by default. Replacing `Set-Content` by `Out-File` in your last attempt in your question will give you the file you want:

```
Select-String -Pattern "\w" -Path 'c:\outpath\contents.txt' | foreach {$_.line} | 
Out-File -FilePath c:\outpath\contents2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not 'r (apostrophe), it's a back tick: `r. That's the key above the tab key on the US keyboard layout. :)

Comment: OopsI typoed it up there, but in my actual script it's `n

Answer (score 1):

You can simply avoid all those empty lines by using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`:

```
Get-ChildItem "$SearchPath" -Recurse | 
    Where { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | 
    Out-File "$OutPath\Contents.txt" -Encoding ASCII -Width 200
```

... if you don't need the folder names.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need the folder names

Comment: I was messing with a similar problem the other day. Isn't there a FullPath property? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter It looks like OP needs the files grouped by folder. I tried to accomplish this by `Select-Object DirectoryName, Name` and `-GroupBy DirectoryName` but this yields the same result like the original command.

Comment: Correct, I need them grouped by folder.